# Heroku charges for CronJob all the time?

Tags: heroku

I want to release a small program on heroku. It has an built in cronjob scheduler.

```
def cronJob():
    asyncio.run(main())

scheduler = BlockingScheduler()

scheduler.add_job(cronJob, 'cron', hour=8, minute=0)

scheduler.add_job(cronJob, 'cron', hour=17, minute=0)

try:
    scheduler.start()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
```

So my question is, does heroku charge me for every hour the program runs so all the time or does it just bills me the few minutes my main function runs two times a day for like a minute? And which Dyno should I use?

In the future I want to add some more cron job functions to the same project it should work with that too.

Comment: Are you still having trouble with this?

Answer (score 0):

That's a Python library trying to *emulate* cron. A [real cron process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) isn't part of your code, it's something that runs separately on the server.

You've got a process that sits idle all day, waiting to do something. Occasionally, it does something. But it needs to run all the time, so your dyno needs to run all the time, so Heroku charges you all the time.

Instead of doing this with Python, use the [Heroku Scheduler](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler). Simply tell it when you want to run something, tell it what command to run, and you're done. Heroku will only charge you for the job while it is running.

**Note:** Heroku Scheduler may run things at slightly different times than you request, and [occasionally it may run things twice or not at all](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler#scheduler-is-a-free-add-on). In my experience, this is exceedingly rare.

If that's not acceptable, you can run a [custom clock process](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduled-jobs-custom-clock-processes) but in that case you're back to running a dyno constantly (as in your question), and you'll be billed accordingly.